# Spark dynamoDB integration

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Apache Spark for a streaming application. I am trying to store the processed data into dynamodb using Java SDK. Getting the following exception:

```
16/12/08 23:23:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration.isInRegionOptimizedModeEnabled()Z
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:35)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:374)
```

Spark version - 1.6.1, Scala version - 2.10.5, AWS SDK version - 1.11.33

Has anyone faced this issues?